# Is there another name for "terminal ground bar"?

Tags: components

I am trying to source this part http://www.theelectricbrewery.com/10-terminal-50A-ground-bar, but I can't find it at digikey. Is there another name?

Comment: While product recs are off-topic here -- you'll have better luck at an electrician's supply house with the type of thing you're looking for. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ground-bar** is correct. But online purchase source may be better choice.

https://www.amazon.com/s?k=10+terminal+ground+bar+kit

- Siemens ECGB10 Ground Bar Kit with 10 Terminal Positions
- Square D by Schneider Electric PK23GTACP 23 Terminal Load Center Ground Bar Kit
- PK3GTA1CP 3" Terminal Ground Bar Kit

or

**POWER DISTRIBUTION BLOCK**
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/adafruit-industries-llc/737/1528-1520-ND/5774323
[image]